# Should i use HTML comments in my email templates?

Tags: html, email, comments

Trying to see if there are any negatives to adding HTML comments to my html emails?

Any feedback is great.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason to have them? I generally like to take most comments out of production code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think so. I've made several professional e-mail templates for Outlook that contained a little notice in the comments. I've never had any problems with that.
I even had fun to see that I could find an e-mail sent by a customer, because Google had indexed it, including the comment. :D

It does increase the size of the e-mail a little, so use with care.

Comment: This is what i assumed but just wanted to confirm it with others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

None, unless the number of comments are too many that they affect DOM parsing by the browser/email client and congest network traffic.

Comment: Yah i think that i will only have a few to just let the coder know where each section is

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're revealing secrets of your network, I don't see anything wrong with it. Allot of systems have comments to highlight template system areas.

Comment: Right, just some section comments really.

Answer (score 0):

Two drawbacks :

1. It makes the e-mail bigger. You should consider it if time or bandwidth is an issue, say if you are going to send thousands of e-mails.
2. It means your e-mail is in HTML, which is to be avoided if possible at all.

Comment: Also bear in mind that every recipient of the email can (theoretically) read the comments. So if you do go down that road, be careful what you write :-)

Comment: Yah main reason to add them is for the person that is modifying them to parse the sections quickly without needed to know where one section starts and ends

Comment: This is a very old answer and no longer useful. HTML emails are perfectly fine in 2019! :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, but I would be careful with any sort of emails with html content. Html in email is particularly tricky because the clients (aol, outlook, gmail, thunderbird, etc) can display the results quite differently. A quick google search brought me to emailonacid.com, an email testing/deliverability tool which might be useful if you want to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I ran into recently was that comments in email HTML should be avoided when nesting around MSO code (used for visibility/layout issues with MS products). I had an image refuse to load in Outlook.com because the MSO text was located in-between two of my comments. The syntax seemed to confuse Outlook in particular. Drove me bats. Then I took the comments out, wham -- the image displayed, problem solved.